# Competition Physics Book for High School Physics

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I am currently a high school physics student who has recently started participating in some physics competitions. Although I have an alright understanding of the physics and mathematics and can usually answer any content questions with an average textbook, I was wondering if anyone may know a good physics book with an emphasis on solving very difficult problems, instead of teaching and explaining the physics, in a sort of workbook with answers format. I see using a book like this as being extremely helpful when training to tackle tests such as the USAPhO or PuPC.

Answer (score 1):

The book you are looking for is called "A decade of SIN plus 16" it has questions and solutions from first twenty six years of the Sir Isaac Newton (SIN) contest run by the University of Waterloo.  [check the Where can I find more practice exams question here](https://uwaterloo.ca/sir-isaac-newton-exam/about-sir-isaac-newton-exam/frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 1):

check out "problems in general physics' by IE Irodov . Another good book is '200 puzzling problems' by peter gnadig .Both are IPhO level problem collections.If you find them too easy try your hand at Jaan Kalda's IPhO handouts . These are probably the kind of books you are looking for. they contain extremely hard problems. IE irodov is the easiest out of them, and it requires only a good understanding of calculus(and physics , obviously) . Jaan Kalda is the hardest.